# Is it possible to bypassing std::cin after a specified amount of time?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to skip user input after X seconds.

Something like:

```
 std::cout << "Enter a number \n";
 timer(5000)
 {
      std::cin >> number;
 }
 //the rest of the program.
```

Anything like this exist?

Comment: What system(s) do you want this to work on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing that's even close to portable. For that matter, there's probably nothing that works directly with iostreams.

Given that you want it for Windows, you could use the console API directly. In particular, you can use `WaitForSingleObject` on the standard input handle, and give a timeout:

```
HANDLE standard_input = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

if (WaitForSingleObject(standard_input, 5000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    // read what the user entered
else
    // timed out (or otherwise failed).
```

Comment: Is there a preprocessor directive I need to include? I'm getting errors in regard to scope.

Comment: You need to `#include <windows.h>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a site that could explain exactly what this does, so I understand it deeper than just copypaste.

Comment: @Justin: The obvious starting point would be the documentation for GetStdHandle and (especially) WaitForSingleObject on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Not really: even if this input is executed on a separate thread, `operator>>()` is not a cancellation point.

But, just for fun of it, here's a contrived approach using boost.asio:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
boost::asio::streambuf readbuffer(100);
int n = 0;
void readhandler(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if(!error)
   {
      const char* buf = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(readbuffer.data());
      std::string result(buf, bytes_transferred);
      std::istringstream is(result);
      is >> n;
   }
}
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioserv;
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor streamdesc(ioserv); 
    streamdesc.assign(0); // filedesc of stdin
    streamdesc.async_read_some(
                    readbuffer.prepare(readbuffer.max_size()),
                    boost::bind(readhandler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    std::cout << "You have 5 seconds to enter a number: " << std::flush;
    boost::thread server(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioserv));
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5)); // or timed_wait
    ioserv.stop();
    server.join();
    std::cout << "The number entered was " << n << '\n';
}
```